# The requested Token and the session Token are not same

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, csrf

*Firstly, sorry for my bad English*

I have created a fresh project via this command :

```
laravel new blog
```

Then, I've ran `make:auth` inside of the blog project.

Then I tried to login to the blog using this address :

localhost:8000/login

Everything works fine and I can login into the blog without any problems!

*I also created the user table and added some users into it!*

**The Problem :**

The problem starts when I deploy this very simple project on the Host. When this project is deployed on the Host and trying to login into it, it gets me :

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

It's weird because it works on localhost but doesn't on Host!

**What I have tried so far :**

I've tried to find out where the user requested Token is comparing to the token one on the session. I figured out that there is a method called `tokensMatch` in the following file :

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

I modified that method to this :

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        $sessionToken = $request->session()->token();

        $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
        $myArray = [        // I added this line
            'SessionToken' => $sessionToken,
            'RequetedToken' => $token,
        ];
        var_dump($myArray); // I added this line
        die();              // I added this line
        if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
            $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
        }

        if (! is_string($sessionToken) || ! is_string($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        return hash_equals($sessionToken, $token);
    }
```

So, then I tried to login in the localhost and the output was this :

```
Array
(
    [sessionToken] => YhfaZMkbEPwWdYmT4D1kyZeysEhFnltROvMgvRQh
    [RequestedToken] => YhfaZMkbEPwWdYmT4D1kyZeysEhFnltROvMgvRQh
)
```

It it shows that the requested Token and the session token are equal and I can login successfully.

But then I try to login on the Host, the output was this :

```
Array
(
    [sessionToken] => GSXeJSwD1mVSQ5XwgbLjnIk3VfhT5GzsiijfE15e
    [RequestedToken] => Nd540vhx5BDidQb2FwudHWRzkK65IIhjgEBcf9ur
)
```

As you can see the requested Token and the session token are diferent! so I can't login into it and it get's me that horrible `TokenMismatchException` error!

It doesn't make sense to me! I have no idea why!

Any helps would be great appreciated

**UPDATE :**

Here is my `auth/login.blade.php` file conttent :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because you dont open the form the right way (please share the HTML) which results in not sending a token.

using [Laravel Form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
//
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> Adding The CSRF Token To A Form Laravel provides an easy method of
>   protecting your application from cross-site request forgeries. First,
>   a random token is placed in your user's session. If you use the
>   Form::open method with POST, PUT or DELETE the CSRF token will be
>   added to your forms as a hidden field automatically. Alternatively, if
>   you wish to generate the HTML for the hidden CSRF field, you may use
>   the token method:
>
> echo Form::token();

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm using Laravel's default Auth system. Do you mean Laravel using Form in a wrong way?! ( I don't think so! ). Anyway I tried your approach but get the same error! Nothing changed!

Comment: @user41888 Can you share your html? im talking about not sending the csrf token on the post.

Comment: @user41888 did you follow these guidelines? https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: When I was trying to do your suggest about using Form facade, yes I did follow that guidline

Comment: @user41888 are you by any chance trying to post to the form from a different domain?

Comment: I have tried to post the Form from different domains and servers! But nothing changed! It returns me the same error!

Comment: @user41888 if your doing cross domain post check out https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors